# What are providers in the Ethereum?

Tags: web3-providers

The below given code is from the a tutorial given here at [one of the tutorials on Truffle](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop)

```
// Set the provider for our contract
App.contracts.Adoption.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
```

I see we set up a Web3 provider for the contract.

What basically are providers? What do they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web3 is a client to connect to the blockchain. But

1- you need to tell web3 which blockchain you are connecting to.

2- After you are connected to the specified blockchain, you need to send messages or data to the web3

those 2 tasks are done by a provider.

Answer (score 6):

A provider links to a running node. For instance `parity` or `geth`.

A node has the ability to view and interact with the blockchain.

Comment: This seems to me as the most accurate answer

Answer (score 6):

https://api.myetherapi.com/eth is a provider. Web3 provider is a website running geth or parity node which talks to Ethereum network.

Comment: Link is broken...

Comment: Looks like they have taken down the whole website.

Answer (score -1):

Initial guess is that this is a web3.js Strategy Pattern to allow an underlying protocol e.g. https to provide access to a node. I will confirm later.